# If $Y \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a+1, 1), U_0 \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0, 1), U = U_0^\frac1a$, why $YU \sim \operatorname{Gamma} (a, 1)$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given random variables like below:

> $Y \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a + 1, 1)$
>
> $U_0 \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$
>
> $U = U_0^\frac1a$

If $Y$  and $U_0$ is independent,

How can I proof $X=YU \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a, 1)$ ?

I tried to solve this problem with theorem $f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(h_1(u,v), h_2(u,v))|J|$

But I'm confusing what should be preimage.

Comment: Please try to add some context to your questions. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the moment generating function of $YU$. Use independence to make it equal to MGF of $Y$ times MGF of $U$. Look up the gamma MGF and uniform MGF and then times them together, and see that it is also gamma.

Comment: Are you sure $MGF(XY) = MGF(X)MGF(Y)$? I cannot see how you could untangle exponents under integral even in the case of independent $Y$ and $Y$. It is usually stated as a fact for sum of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Again, like in [If $Y\sim\operatorname{Beta}(a,1-a)$ and $Z\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$, then $YZ\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231727/if-y-sim-operatornamebetaa-1-a-and-z-sim-operatornameexp1-then-yz/3234680#3234680) we will be using [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) to get image of the product, using the fact, that image of the product is the product of Mellin images. For $U(0,1)^{\frac{1}{a}}$ we could easily reconstruct PDF

$$
PDF_X(x) = a x^{a-1} 1_{0<x<1}
$$

Its Mellin image is

$$
M(X) = \frac{a}{s+a-1}
$$

For Gamma-distribution

$$
M(Y) = \frac{\Gamma(s+a-1+1)}{\Gamma(a+1)}
$$

Therefore

$$
M(XY) = \frac{\Gamma(s+a-1+1)}{s+a-1} \frac{a}{\Gamma(a+1)} = \frac{\Gamma(s+a-1)}{\Gamma(a)}  
$$

using well-known property of Gamma-function. Which is obviously could be transformed back to

$$
PDF(x|XY) = M^{-1}\{\frac{ \Gamma(s+a-1) }{\Gamma(a)} \} = \frac{ \exp(-x) x^{a-1} }{\Gamma(a)} 1_{x>0}
$$

which is obviously Gamma distribution